# Run django app automatically in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python

How would I run my django app in Raspberry Pi automatically?

Cause doing runserver is really manual, I like it to be working whenever I open my browser and boom, my django app is ready. How?

Answer (score 1):

Add the start command to the last row of `/etc/rc.local` .

Ref.: Raspberry Pi official documentation. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md